# A-Frame async timing issue with component

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, html5-canvas, aframe

I have written an A-Frame component that creates a canvas on which it writes an image.  The image is generated dynamically from HTML.  The HTML is created when a message arrives from a server, using WebSockets, asynchronously.  The problem is that most often (but not always) the canvas is drawn blank.  I have tested the component using hardcoded HTML, and it works just as expected, so the issue must be one of timing, but I don't know why or how to solve it.

Schematically, the code is:

In a JS module file, `vr.js`:

```js
// Observe the arrival of the websocket message, then
// Create the HTML based on the message and save it as 'legend'

let legendBox = document.getElementById('legend')
legendBox.innerHTML = legend
legendBox.components.showHTML.update();
```

In the HTML file:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<script src="../js/vr.js" type="module"></script>

        AFRAME.registerComponent('showHTML', {
                init: function () {},
                update: function () {
                    if (this.el.getObject3D('screen')) this.remove()
                    if (this.el.innerHTML.trim() === '') return
                    this.htmlcanvas = new HTMLCanvas(this.el)
                    let texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(this.htmlcanvas.canvas)
                    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
                    texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
                    texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
                    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        map: texture,
                        transparent: true,
                    })
                    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1)
                    let screen = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
                    this.el.setObject3D('screen', screen)
                    this.screen = screen
                    this.resize()
                },
                resize() {
                    this.width = this.htmlcanvas.width / this.data.ppu
                    this.height = this.htmlcanvas.height / this.data.ppu
                    this.screen.scale.x = Math.max(0.0001, this.width)
                    this.screen.scale.y = Math.max(0.0001, this.height)
                    this.htmlcanvas.render()
                },
                remove: function () {
                    this.el.removeObject3D('screen')
                },
            })
            class HTMLCanvas {
                constructor(html) {
                    if (!html) throw 'Container Element is Required'

                    // Create the canvas to be drawn to
                    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
                    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')

// code to extract the innerHTML from the entity, transform it into an SVG, 
// and load the SVG into an image -- all omitted for simplicity

                // Renders the image containing the SVG to the Canvas
                render() {
                    this.canvas.width = this.width
                    this.canvas.height = this.height
                    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
                    this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0)
                }

            } // end class
     } // end of component
</head>
<body>
        <a-scene>

// usual A-Frame entities omitted

            <a-entity id="legend" position="-1 1 -2" showHTML></a-entity>

// more A-Frame stuff including camera etc.

        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd test it not with hardcoded HTML, but with a drawable canvas + interval updates. Also you could probably just call `texture.needsUpdate = true;` instead of creating the mesh anew.

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Thank you for this suggestion.  Could you expand on what you mean - could you show what changes would be needed to my code?